# Avg thinks my program is a hack tool when I include windows.h

Tags: c++

I have a blank c++ project and when I include `windows.h`  and try to run it, avg pops up and says it's a hack tool. (I've tested it, just including the header file sets it off.)

I've added my programming folder as an exception so I can run it but I wouldn't want to distribute a program like that is there something I can do differently to satisfy avg?

Note: I'm trying to follow an OpenGL tutorial.

Edit: The program compiles fine without the windows header file and avg pops up when I do include it but how else can a form be made?

Here's a screenshot:
[image: AVG error]

Comment: Er... what's the exact error message? Is there a screenshot we can see?

Comment: I don't think AVG is going to divulge their heuristics for what is or is not considered a hack tool—that would just make it easier for malware authors to evade AVG's detection.

Comment: Get your money back from AVG.

Comment: Do you write to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE or inside the "Program Files" folder?

Comment: The name of the EXE you are producing likely matches something AVG's database.  Just rename the project and output executable to something completely different.  That is, don't be building something called "hackertool.exe" (or whatever you are calling it.)  Call it something else.

Comment: @selbie: play_mp3.exe is a fine alternative.

Comment: Call it AVG.exe. That will probably go over well.

Comment: @selbie: the name isn't a problem it only happens when the windows header file is included.

Comment: Check your Windows header. Perhaps AVG is right and your header file has been modified by malware.

Comment: @Justin: I tried scanning it but it says its fine.

Comment: The screenshot show a 'hello world' program - is that really all that's needed to get the AV program to complain?  Does this happen with a new project as well?

Comment: @Michael: The windows header file alone sets it off.

Comment: Try to add it to avg exceptions.

Comment: @Adilson Try explaining that your customers.

Comment: Iv read that the MFC apps already include the windows header? but AVG doesn't pop up on an MFC app, is there a compiling option I need to change?

Comment: Perhaps AVG gets confused by callbacks injected by the debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building in release mode fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it isn't Visual Studio which has a virus? Or the libraries?

You might be drawing in a compromised .DLL, can you recompile an old known-working program?

Comment: I can write programs without avg popping up but as soon as I include the windows.h header file and build the solution avg pops up. I don't have any other projects that use this header as Iv been using C# for the past 2 years and now I'm learning c++.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your screenshot and description, this sounds like it could be expected behavior.  This would depend on your settings in AVG.  Think about what AVG is observing when you run a newly compiled binary:  it is detecting a binary (that it has never scanned) trying to access system libraries.

I'm not familiar with AVG's settings, but I'd recommend seeing if you could change how it reacts to unknown and unscanned applications.  Let us know if a certain setting change lets you run unhindered (short of completely disabling it of course).

Comment: Actually building my program in release mode fixed the problem but my answer seems to have been deleted.

Comment: @Alex: A moderator deleted it, without warning, because you asked for more clarification (which usually wouldn't happen in an _answer_). I think that this is short-sighted, because the answer did contain the solution.

Comment: @Tomalak I seem to remember that the answer was also along the lines of "In release I have no problem. It only happens in debug. So it's solved". (Not those exact words of course). That is not an answer but merely circumvents the problem in my opinion. Maybe I'm mistaken in remembering the "answer" though?

Comment: @Bart: It says "Building the solution in debug mode makes AVG pop up but building in release mode doesn't. So the problem is solved but I would be interested to find out why this is? I don't know why I decided to try that now but thanks for all the suggestions anyways."

Comment: @Alex: You should probably edit your answer so it includes that information.

Answer (score 0):

AVG is right... windows.h has windows system calls in it and AVG mis-understands it as a illegitimate code.

Add the file as 'safe' to the AVG database on your machine and it will not bother you again.